# Example Project For How to use MKNetworkKit

Tags: objective-c, ios, networking

I'm new to iOS development.

I don't know how to use & where to start MKNetworkKit for my project.

Can anyone share an example project which is using MKNetworkKit.

thanks,
Jirune

Comment: [Here I found a simpler example for a basic use.](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/asihttprequest-is-dead-now-what/) This one does not subclass MKNetworkKit.

Comment: Looks like some Neo-Nazi converted my post into a comment. Well, I hope it helps somebody, but talk about censorship. They give google hell for smaller stuff.

Comment: Don't fret subclassing :) MKNetworkKit can be used with or without subclassing

Comment: How to use without subclassing?

Answer (score 2):

Just follow a good tutorial. I used this tutorial when I first used it [Advanced Networking with MKNetworkKit](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/ios-tutorial-advanced-networking-with-mknetworkkit/) goes through quite a bit. This is the blog post they reference in the readme. Sometimes it helps to read through that :)

You can eve find a [iOS demo](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKNetworkKit/tree/master/iOS-Demo) on the GitHub Page